# How to detect which views that are in use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have started to write my map routes like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Image/{fileID}/{width}/{height}/{fileName}",
  (ContentController c) => c.Thumbnail(SITE_ID, FILE_ID, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null));
```

(having my own extender class that defines my own MapRoute function)

and I am also referring to actions in a strictly way like this:

```
var foo = "@Url.Action((FileManagerController c)=> c.Select(0, 0, null, null))"
```

...again including some of my own magic.

Now I easily can see which controllers and actions that are in use. And I can use F12 navigation etc etc.

But... how can I know which views I use?

Are they classes with some strange names?

Comment: What do you mean by "use" ? The one linked with actions ? What about partial views ?

Comment: Views that are not dead code. Views which files just cannot be deleted.

Comment: you do realise that it would be much nicer to use type inference?

Comment: **Question**: How do you determine which controllers and actions are *actually* being used? By searching files manually and seeing their types? You could do the same looking for `return Partial(` and `return View(`. And just so you know: not all references to controller actions may be accessed using those two extensions methods you've written. **So this is not really a bullet proof *controller action coverage* technique...**

Comment: .. and you do realise as well that naming variables using upper case (that you're providing to method parameters) isn't really following naming conventions... And when I was talking about type inference I actually wanted to say *generic extension methods* ie: `Url.Action<FileManagerController>(c => c.Select(...))`.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see where I could have used type inference, but did not. I am a big fan of type inference.

Comment: To see where controllers and actions that are really used, I use the resharper plugin. There is a "find usages" operation which can list where a certain method is used. If the only place is in the route mapping file, it is time to remove an action. Another way that I think would do good is to temporarily comment out the route mappings and see which actions that turn gray (by resharper).

Comment: Although I am not seeking a bullet proof technique to programmatically reference actions, I am curious about knowing which actions that could be problematic to do so with.

Comment: I suppose the only way of detecting dead views is to write some kind of unit tests, although I fail to find out a way to write them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC).

It strongly types all of your views via T4 templates.  It will allow you to figure out information about your views as you would any other class.